# Can someone please explain how this circuit works

Tags: analog, communication, sound, modulation, laser

It's s simple transmitter for light modulating certain sound we input to it. But i can't seem to know how this modulates the input signal.[image]

Comment: Well all I can say to "Armand and Victor" is trying any harder to destroy a laser diode would be criminal.

Comment: The transformer adds the audio signal to the 5 V DC, the transistor is used as an emitter follower so it basically buffers that 5V + audio. This is fed to laserdiode + series resistor so the voltage and current are modulated. And I think this falls in the category of crappy circuits. You will have high expectations of it but in the end, it does not work very well.

Comment: @Andyaka It's funny though, how the "Full power" option doesn't even do what they want it to.

Comment: I like how the capacitors around the voltage regulator are considered _"Not essential"_

Comment: @tuskiomi - What do you think they want it to do? I imagine that "full power" option is there to keep the laser on for aiming at the receiver.

Comment: @Bort it's for one of 2 things: sound transmission, or etching records. Can't imagine etching records at full power is very useful.

Comment: @tuskiomi - "Full power" has the output of the regulator going directly to the laser diode. Therefor, the laser will be held ON. I'm saying that would be helpful for aiming the laser at the receiver. What are you saying?

Comment: @Bort that a full power laser that's meant to etch a record would just melt the record. if it's meant to transmit sound, then it's an eye hazard. surely half power would be sufficient?

Comment: The transistor functions as an emitter follower ONLY if it's collector is connected to a voltage source that's higher than the signal voltage (base voltage). Otherwise, it just functions as a diode (the B-E junction). Definitely a crappy circuit.

Comment: Pro choice, D13009: NPN, VCBO 700V, hfe 20

Comment: @tuskiomi - OP's image shows the laser sending a signal to a receiver that connects to an audio amplifier. As for "*surely half power would be sufficient*", perhaps, but what does that have to do with it? You said "*Full power option doesn't even do what they want it to*", I'm asking you to tell me how it doesn't do what they want.

Comment: okay up to now i am sure that the circuit is shitty. So can you please help me to improve it. I am new to electronics and i wanted to do this as the first DIY the coming weekend.But certainly it's not a good circuit. please help me make it better.

Comment: @Bort Perhaps going from 0 to full power could blow out the speakers?

Comment: @tuskiomi - Perhaps you are just completely guessing and have no idea if it does what they want or not? You said it doesn't do what they want...but you can't even say why.

Comment: @Bort That doesn't absolve the circuit of it's problems.

Comment: @tuskiomi - That doesn't make your statement "*Full power option doesn't even do what they want it too*" correct. I didn't say the circuit didn't have problems.

Comment: @Bort and the same can be said for attacking the ethos of a logically driven argument. Regardless, you seem to have no interest in the actual problems of this circuit, but rather pointing out my incompetency. I assure you, I've let you know of some possible problems of this circuit, and you still intend on pressing for no good reason. I'm done here.

Comment: @tuskiomi - I just wanted to know how "full power" didn't work as intended, and you are unable to say how. Everything else is irrelevant because I didn't ask about anything else. I see no logic on your part. You claimed "X", I asked how X is true, and you have provided numerous comments, none of which explain X. I provided an example of how X could be false. It's not a big deal, I just don't see why you made a claim and refuse to just admit that X is unfounded.

Comment: The capacitors around the regulator, the anti-backflow diode and the inrush limiting resistor aren't "essential" but the power-indicator LED is?

Answer (score 2):

This circuit give the user the choice of how the laser is drive :

- In the 1st position (switch is as the drawing), the voltage coming from the jack + transformer lead will trigger the transistor and then power or not the laser diode. So the state of the diode depend of the voltage coming from the jack.
- In the 2nd position, the laser diode is always power on because it's directly connected to the 7805 (5V voltage regulator)

Answer (score 2):

> But i can't seem to know how this modulates the input signal.

It all happens very, very quickly then the laser diode no longer functions (it burns on too much current). It burns because the laser current needs to be limited below \$I_{OP}\$ as indicated below: -

[image]

Above the threshold current it lases, below the threshold it glows and, above the operating limit it never works again as a laser. Theshold and maximum current might be as little as 1:1.5 so decent care is needed to avoid breaking it.

A 7805 fed from a 9 volt supply will be capable of putting 1 amp into the laser diode and, for most low power devices, destroying it.

So, in the longer run you should consider a circuit that stands a much better chance of longer-term success. A simple option is to feed the laser from a constant voltage supply current limited by a resistor. The resistor value is chosen so that it biases the laser at approximately halfway up its operating region. To choose the resistor valuee you need the data sheet of the laser.

Then, you can inject audio carefully via another resistor (and series capacitor) to the anode of the laser. In this way you are modulating the DC current that flows through the laser and thus producing modulated light. But don't be eager to over-modulate else you'll destroy the laser by pumping too much peak current into it.

Another method is to use this: -

[image]

As depicted above and with R4 and R5 values producing a || 0.5 ohms, this could be regarded as high power and unsuitable for a lot of low power lasers so, read your laser data sheet and choose R4 and R5 to restrict the current to the middle region as described above and as shown in the characteristic diagram.

You can inject audio via a capacitor and resistor to the non-inverting input of the op-amp. RV1 can be used to tweak the laser bias point. You might also want to consider how the threshold current is affected by temperature and compensate for this with a thermistor circuit: -

[image]

For instance, if you chose 60 mA at 25 degC then you would get bad audio distortion at 50 degC where, ideally you would want to run at 80 mA. But running at 80 mA at 25 degC is going to be too much so, a compensation circuit can prove useful.

And finally.....

### USE LASER DIODES VERY CAREFULLY BECAUSE THEY CAN BLIND ESPECIALLY THE INFRARED TYPES BECAUSE YOU CAN'T SEE THE GLOW.

Comment: actually, your power Vs current graphs are a bit off. They look more like this: [BDR-209 405nm diode](http://i.imgur.com/uAvNRAz.png) or this:  [NDG7475 520nm diode](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1280x1024q90/922/7tbr6K.png).  The ones you provide seem to show the effects of minimum voltage.

Comment: There is a current limiting resistor down on the negative rail.

Comment: @tuskiomi I have no idea what laser is being proposed. It doesn't seem to be stated in the question but I may have missed it. So, I have used general pictures found on the web and my background knowledge driving IR Hamamatsu lasers,

Comment: @ratchetfreak it seems to me that any resistor marked "0-? \$\Omega\$" will be fitted as a short circuit by someone not-in-the-know - what value would you fit?

Comment: Fair, I guess If I boil it down, it's that lasers have a wide range of currents, but small voltage range. You seem to convey this effectively, but I like to add some references.

Comment: @tuskiomi I'm not stopping you making an answer using a higher power laser with data taken from its data sheet! "I'm done here" to quote you hehe.